# Incorrect name returned in Tensorflow causes "Tensor which does not exist" error while invoking get_tensor_by_name

Tags: tensorflow, namespaces

As per the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graphs#naming_operations) TensorFlow would append "_1", "_2", and so on to the name in tf.Graph namespace, in order to make it unique.  Here I define two convolutional operations.  It is expected that the first one will be named as "conv2d" and second one "conv2d_1".  But when I try to obtain the name of the second convolution it returns "conv2d_2".  I causes error when I try to invoke get_tensor_by_name. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import os

x = tf.constant(np.random.randn(1,2,2,1), dtype=tf.float32)
kernel_size = (1,1)
no_of_out = 20
strides = (1,1)
conv_out1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 10, (1,1), (1,1))
conv_out2 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 10, (1,1), (1,1))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print conv_out1.name # conv2d/BiasAdd:0 .  This value is correct
    print conv_out2.name # conv2d_2/BiasAdd:0 .  This value is incorrect.  It should be conv2d_1/BiasAdd:0
    conv_weights1 = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(os.path.split(conv_out1.name)[0] + '/kernel:0')
    conv_weights2 = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('conv2d_1/kernel:0')  
    conv_weights2 = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(os.path.split(conv_out2.name)[0] + '/kernel:0')
```

I could not understand why conv_out2.name returns "conv2d_2" instead of "conv2d_1"

Comment: I obtained error 

KeyError: "The name 'conv2d_2/kernel:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'conv2d_2/kernel', does not exist in the graph."

Comment: Raised issue here

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19991#issuecomment-397134300